# Disable editing in wxWidgets listctrl

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Good evening,

I need to disable the editing cells in wxWindows listctrl class. i'm use it as a report-style control. Can't find out how to disable this feature. are there smth. like 'Edit' event for it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wxListCtrl` is not editable by default, you must be specifying `wxLC_EDIT_LABELS` when creating it to make it editable in the first place. So simply not using this style should do what you want.

Comment: Yes, those flag was the reason for this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems i found the problem.

i used the "EVT_LIST_BEGIN_LABEL_EDIT" event and then, in handler 'Veto()'-ed the event. for my app logic it's enough so far:)

Comment: This works, but is mostly useful for preventing the user from editing _some_ items in an otherwise editable control. If you don't want to allow editing _any_ items, it's better to follow the recommendation in my answer.